# Mongoose Populate - Missing Schema Error, but the schema is properly registered for the model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Last day of 2021! After spending just over 5 hours scouring the internet I've resorted to posting for help.

Desired Behaviour:

- the list of documents returned by the route will contain populated documents instead of only the ref ids

Attempted Resolutions:

- added exec function after populate
- Stackoverflow lead me down a rabbit hole of believing the issue was related to mongoose connections, and so I revamped the backend so that my model files returned schemas instead of models, and then used mongoose.createConnection instead of .connect, and made a db.js module to hold a single instance of each model (connection.mode()) that route files could then access and share. I did not reach a point where I could test .populate so I git reset back to the below code

**Error**

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "progressions".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

Note that this error is thrown when trying to populate "lesson" as well

**Progress Model**

```
const Progress = mongoose.model('Progress', new Schema({
  lesson: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'lesson'
  },
  progressions: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'progression'
  }],
  progress:{
    type: Number
  },
  user:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  }
},{
  timestamps: true,
}));

module.exports = Progress;
```

**Progress Routes File**

```
router.get('/all', async (req, res) => {
  let user = await User.find({email:req.query.user})
  let data = await Progress.find({user:user}).populate('progressions')
  return res.status(201).json({
     data,
    message: 'data populated',
    success: true
  });
});
```

**Progression Model**

```
const Progression = mongoose.model('Progression', new Schema({

  type:{
    type:String
  },
  toBeReviewed:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
},{
  timestamps: true,
}));

module.exports = Progression;
```

Comment: Can you post your `progressions` model code?

Comment: are you sure that progessions is Model name instead of collection name?

Comment: @LucaPizzini I have added the Progression model code

Comment: @MarcoBertelli thanks for catching that. I fixed the typo, please see edited code. 'progression' is the name of the model. One Progress can reference an array of Progression(s) under a field called 'progressions'. So in .populate I put the field name 'progressions'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the `progressions` property `ref` attribute in the `Progress` schema to match the `Progression` model name (capitalize it):

```
progressions: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Progression'
}]
```

Comment: You saved me! I never thought to capitalize because the tutorials I saw for basic CRUD worked with lowercase. I learned something new. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is late, but for anyone is still having errors. Try using the model instead

```
import {progressionModel} from "../Progression.model";
progressions: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: progressionModel
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

All code in your mongoose files should have run before it is used in other files.

This error could be happening because your mongoose models aren't executed before they are used in some other file.

Comment: This code is executed after the authentication process.  I don't have any issue querying any models. Its only when I add .populate at the end that the error was thrown. Would mongoose files not have finished running by then?

Comment: @Luckyfield I think mongoose might be treating "progressions" as a model. And because of that you are getting the missing schema error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

did you try using "Progressions"  while passing it in populate ?

Comment: I had - unfortunately since the field name is lowercase I got an error saying "Progressions" was not registered in the schema.